# NSMutableAttributedString crashes when changing fonts for different ranges

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

So I'm trying to change the colors of a NSMutableAttributedString but I keep getting an out of bounds exception error when I try to add multiple ranges (see below). If on the other hand I just do a single range from 0 to totalLength-1, there is no issue. I don't know why this is happening.

My code is below:

```
NSString *testString = @"This is my test string for this example";   

NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]     initWithString:testString];
int totalLength = [playerTurnString length];


[playerTurnString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 11)];
[playerTurnString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(12, totalLength-1)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `NSRange` is a location and a length, so when you do

> NSMakeRange(12, totalLength-1)

Your length is 12 too long and therefore exceeds the range of the string. You're trying to use it as a start and end location but that isn't how it works.